# Swapping positions in an array

Tags: c++

How do I  swap the position of two items in a list ( using arrays) in c++.
using an array. This is my function that is supposed to accomplish this task. I've assigned a name to the different elements in an array. The variables here have already been defined.

```
    while (i <= 5)
    {
        if (arr[i] == name1){
            arr[i] = x;
            x = tempName;
            y = x;
            x = y;
            cout << y << x << endl;
        }
        if (arr[i]== name2){
            arr[i] = y;

            y = tempName;
            x = y;
            y = x;
            cout << y << x << endl;

        }

             i = i + 1;
    }
    if (arr[i] != name1 || arr[i] != name2)
    {
        cout << "You have to pick a name from the line up" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: i've been stuck on this one for a while but i cant get my function working.

Comment: "list" can refer to a linked-list which is not the same as an array. Please clarify the data structure type.

Comment: using an array. I've assigned a name to the different elements in an array. and i'm not sure how to look through the array and find and call a specific element from an array so that it can be swapped. Im unsure about the proper syntax.

Comment: @Nina How is this `array` declared? What is the `x` you are assigning to the array element? There's some crazy stuff going on in your code like assigning the value of `y` to `x` and then assigning that value right back to `y`. Unless you've done some amazing (dreadful) things with operators this whole round trip seemed wasted...

Answer (score 2):

By the title of your question, here is how to swap elements of an array:

```
temporary_element = array[i];
array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = temporary_element;
```

I didn't specify the data types because they weren't in your posted question.

Comment: while (i <= 5){
if (arr[i] == name1){
 arr[i] = x;
 x = tempName;
 y = x;
 x = y;
 cout << y << x << endl;
}
if (arr[i]== name2){
    arr[i] = y;

    y = tempName;
    x = y;
    y = x;
    cout << y << x << endl;

   }

     i = i + 1;
  }
  if (arr[i] != name1 || arr[i] != name2)
  {
   cout << "You have to pick a name from the line up" << endl;
  }
*/

Comment: sorry, im not sure how to paste the code so its shows up in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to search, and then swap those elements.
If you do a lot of these, try [std::set<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), or [std::map<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) containers.
For searching in an array, and then swapping them here is a simple code:

```
    int i = 0;
while (i < N && (name1 != arr[i] || name2 != arr[i]))
    ++i;
int id1 = i;
while (i < N && (name1 != arr[i] || name2 != arr[i]) && arr[id1] != arr[i])
    ++i;
int id2 = i;
if (id2 < N)
{
    auto tmp = arr[id1];
    arr[id1] = arr[id2];
    arr[id2] = tmp;
}
```